# string to List of string using substring in c#

Tags: c#, list, substring

I have string containing bullets

> *apple*mango*banana*sapota.

I want to create a list of string `{apple,mango,banana,sapota}`.
Suggest any other method if available

Answer (score 6):

Try using `string.Split` with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` option

```
var list = yourString.Split(new[] {'*'}, 
                    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `string.Split`:

```
var list = yourInput.Trim('*').Split('*').ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string test =  "*apple*mango*banana*sapota";
List<string> l = test.Split('*').ToList();
```

If you want to remove empty entries:

```
string test =  "*apple*mango*banana*sapota";
List<string> l = test.Split('*').Where(x=>x!=String.Empty).ToList();
```

Comment: Removing empty entries can actually be done like this: `test.Split(new[] { '*' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: You are right, but there is already one such answer. I wouldn't like to duplicate it. By the way, do you think that performance wise they are the same or not?

Comment: The performance aspect is hard to comment on. However, it's almost certain that it's **better** to handle empty entries while building the *initial array* (i.e. `string.Split`), rather than iterating the entire array again to remove empty entries.

Comment: Performance will be worse using LINQ. Under the hood they will be doing the same thing (for loop), but LINQ will have a very small over head in using deferred execution at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

`String.Split` is what you're looking for:

[MSDN entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Use this ..

```
 string s = "*apple*mango*banana*sapota.";

 string[] lst = s.Split('*');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str="*apple*mango*banana*sapota";
    List<String> lst = new List<string>();
    String [] strArray= str.Split('*');

    foreach (String str1 in strArray)
    {
       if(str1!="")
        lst.Add(str1);
    }
```

List `lst` Contains `Items` as below:

```
apple
mango
banana
sapota
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    string names = "*apple*mango*banana*sapota";
    List<string> test = new List<string>();
    string[] namesplit = names.Split('*'); 
    foreach(string namearry in namesplit)
    {
        test.Add(namearry);
        test.ToArray();
    }
```